# Bean getting injected without using @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I was doing some @Autowired annotations in my code where I stumbled upon a doubt. I am getting the name as **John** even though I have not injected the Employee bean in GetName.java. The bean was getting injected even though I was not autowiring it using any annotation. Is there some specific prerequisite need to be kept in mind while using constructors ?

Employee.Java

```
package com.sample.employee;

public class Employee {

public String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

GetName.java

```
package com.sample.salary;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.sample.employee.Employee;

public class GetName {

//  @Autowired
    public Employee emp;

//  @Autowired
    public GetName(Employee emp) {
        this.emp = emp;
    }


    public void displayName() {
        System.out.println(emp.getName()); //prints John
    }

}
```

spring.xml

```
<?xml

 version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample.employee"/> -->

    <bean id="empl" class="com.sample.employee.Employee">
        <property name="name" value="John" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="GetNames" class="com.sample.salary.GetName"/>

</beans>
```

MainClass.java

```
    package com.sample.employee;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.sample.salary.SalaryCalculator;

public class MainCLass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    GetName cal = (GetName) context.getBean("GetNames");
    cal.displayName();

}
}
```

Am I missing out something?

Comment: It's unlikely could you add more info like the code where you call GetNames bean

Comment: Sorry I did not get you. I have just used the getName() of the Employee.java in the GetName.java.

Comment: It shouldn't work, you're missing `<constructor-arg ref="empl"/>`. Make sure that you recompile everything and that the code you posted as actually the code you're using. With what you posted you should get "no no-argument constructor" error.

Comment: Exactly @Oleg it should not work. I cleaned my project plus built it but its still executing. If I had used `<constructor-arg ref="empl"/>`then it should have worked in this case (as I am not using @Autowired). But its just compiling fine and giving John as output. Can you try it once.

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2016/03/04/core-container-refinements-in-spring-framework-4-3#implicit-constructor-injection-for-single-constructor-scenarios

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one Constructor for a Bean, Spring will do constructor injection and the `@Autowired` annotation can be omitted.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html

This feature was added with one of the more recent versions.